# Google Data Transfer API says completed but nothing has happened?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm using the Data Transfer API to programmatically transfer the files owned by user A to user B as part of our exit process.

I look up the email addresses for the two users so that I can retrieve their IDs. I also query the list of data transfer applications to get the application ID for "Drive and Docs".

I pass the built transfer definition to the API and get the following JSON back:

```
{
   "kind": "admin#datatransfer#DataTransfer",
   "etag": "\"RV_wOygBiIUZUtakV6Iq44-H_Gw/2M4Z2X_c8OpsyQOJxtWDmIHcYzo\"",
   "id": "AKrEtIbF0aAg_4KK7-lHFOpRNPhcgAOWWDEK1HE0zD_EEY-bOPHXuj1rKNrEE-yHPYyjY8vzvZkK",
   "oldOwnerUserId": "101496053770427062754",
   "newOwnerUserId": "118268322014081744703",
   "applicationDataTransfers": [
      {
         "applicationId": "55656082996",
         "applicationTransferStatus": "pending"
      }
   ],
   "overallTransferStatusCode": "inProgress",
   "requestTime": "2017-03-31T10:50:48.560Z"
}
```

I then query the transfers API to get an update on that transfer and get the following back:

```
{
   'kind': 'admin#datatransfer#DataTransfer',
   'requestTime': '2017-03-31T10:50:48.560Z',
   'applicationDataTransfers': [
      {
         'applicationTransferStatus': 'completed',
         'applicationId': '55656082996'
      }
   ],
   'newOwnerUserId': '118268322014081744703',
   'oldOwnerUserId': '101496053770427062754',
   'etag': '"RV_wOygBiIUZUtakV6Iq44-H_Gw/ZVnLgj3YLcsURTSzNm8m91tNeC0"',
   'overallTransferStatusCode': 'completed',
   'id': 'AKrEtIbF0aAg_4KK7-lHFOpRNPhcgAOWWDEK1HE0zD_EEY-bOPHXuj1rKNrEE-yHPYyjY8vzvZkK'
}
```

and, indeed, I get a confirmation email that the files have been transferred.

However, if I look in Google Drive for both users, the files have NOT changed ownership. For user B, a new directory has been created with the email address of user A, but it contains no files and user A still owns all of their files.

What have I done wrong or misunderstood?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the [Quickstarts](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/quickstart/js)? Doc says it's a full-working sample, however you didn't indicate which language you're using so just gave you the JS one.

Comment: @noogui Although it is a fully working sample, it only displays the applications. I have used that in order to get the correct applicationId for Drive. I'm writing in Python but I'm not using the library that Google provides. I'm just making direct web calls to their end-point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had faced the same issue, please provide  "applicationTransferParams" with key value.

```
  "applicationTransferParams": [
    {
      "key": string,
      "value": [
        string
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Just to clarify on this, I've copied the transferParams data retrieved from the applications call into the transfer resource data block. The files are then successfully transferred.